# Smart Contract Method Reverted in Ganache but Worked Fine in Remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, remix, ganache

**Overview**

I am working on a project for a Blockchain Developer Course, the project must be tested with Ganache because the Reviewer Team for the course will use Ganache.

The Smart Contract that I am working right now works with two different smart contracts, one is for data storage and the other is for the application purposes (user interaction).
When an user interacts with the registerOracle function the smart contract will ask for 1 ether to generate 1 oracle (this oracle will have an ID and 3 Indexes).

I tested the Smart Contract on Remix and everything works find but when I try to test the oracle generator function in Ganache it gives me a revert error.

**Project URL**

The project's files are in my [Github's repository](https://github.com/JaskSkull/GANACHE-ERROR-REPORT) along with some screenshot I took showcasting the procedure to test the smart contract on Remix and the error I get on Ganache.

The code is too extend, but I will be posting here the relevant parts that are giving me the errors. The complete code can be seen on my repository.

**TestingEnv.js File**

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function main () {
    /**
    * IGNORE FROM HERE
    */
    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:8545"));

    const appABI = (JSON.parse(await fs.readFile("./bin/appAbi.json", "utf8"))).abi;
    const appBYTECODE = (JSON.parse(await fs.readFile("./bin/appByteCode.json", "utf8"))).bytecode;

    const dataABI = (JSON.parse(await fs.readFile("./bin/dataAbi.json", "utf8"))).abi;
    const dataBYTECODE = (JSON.parse(await fs.readFile("./bin/dataByteCode.json", "utf8"))).bytecode;

    const owner = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0];

    const appContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(appABI).deploy({data: '0x' + appBYTECODE})
    .send({from: owner, gasLimit: 6000000, gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('5', 'gwei')});

    const dataContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(dataABI).deploy({data: '0x' + dataBYTECODE})
    .send({from: owner, gasLimit: 6000000, gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('5', 'gwei')});

    const appAddress = appContract._address;
    const dataAddress = dataContract._address;

    await appContract.methods.registerDataContract(dataAddress).send({from: owner});
    await dataContract.methods.registerApplicationContract(appAddress).send({from: owner});
    /**
    * TO HERE
    */

    /**
    * REVERT ERROR - STARTS
    */
    const oracleFee = await web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether");
    const server = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[2];
    // I AM REGISTERING 20 ORACLES
    for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
        await appContract.methods.registerOracle().send({from: server, value: oracleFee});
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    };
    const totalOracles = await appContract.methods.getTotalOracles().call({from: server});
    console.log(`Total Numbers of Oracles Registered: ${totalOracles}`);
    for (var i = 0; i<totalOracles; i++) {
        var indexes = await appContract.methods.getOraceIndexes(i).call({from: server});
        if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
            console.log(`Oracle 0${i} indexes: ${indexes._index1.toString()} ${indexes._index2.toString()} ${indexes._index2.toString()}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Oracle ${i} indexes: ${indexes._index1.toString()} ${indexes._index2.toString()} ${indexes._index2.toString()}`);
        };
    };
};

main();
```

**FlightSuretyApp.sol Contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface iFlightSuretyData {
    function registerOracle(address server, uint8 index1, uint8 index2, uint8 index3) external payable;
}

import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract FlightSuretyApp {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    bool operationalStatus;
    address owner;
    iFlightSuretyData FlightSecuretyData;

    constructor() public {
        operationalStatus = true;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier requireOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Owner is required");
        _;
    }

    modifier requireOperational() {
        require(operationalStatus == true, "Contract is not operational");
        _;
    }

    function registerDataContract(address dataContract) external
    requireOwner {
        FlightSecuretyData = iFlightSuretyData(dataContract);
    }

    uint256 constant ORACLE_REGISTRATION_FEE = 1 ether;

    modifier requireOracleRegistrationFee() {
        require(msg.value == ORACLE_REGISTRATION_FEE, "Oracle Registration Cost 1 ether");
    _;
    }

    function registerOracle() external payable
    requireOperational
    requireOracleRegistrationFee {
        (uint8 index1, uint8 index2, uint8 index3) = indexesThrown();
        FlightSecuretyData.registerOracle.value(msg.value)(msg.sender, index1, index2, index3);
    }

    function indexesThrown() private view returns(uint8 _index1, uint8 _index2, uint8 _index3)                
    {
        uint8 index1 = generateIndex1();
        uint8 index2 = generateIndex2(index1);
        uint8 index3 = generateIndex3(index1, index2);
        return (index1, index2, index3);
    }

    function generateIndex1() private view returns(uint8 _index) {
        uint256 mod = 10;
        uint256 time = block.timestamp;
        uint256 difficulty = block.difficulty;
        uint8 value = uint8(SafeMath.mod(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(time, difficulty, msg.sender))), mod));
        return value;
    }

    function generateIndex2(uint8 _index1) private view returns(uint8 _index) {
        uint256 mod = 10;
        uint256 time = block.timestamp;
        uint256 difficulty = block.difficulty;
        uint8 value = uint8(SafeMath.mod(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(time, difficulty, msg.sender))), mod));
        while(value == _index1) {
            time = SafeMath.add(time, 500);
            difficulty = SafeMath.add(difficulty, 700);
            value = uint8(SafeMath.mod(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(time, difficulty, msg.sender))), mod));
        }
        return value;
    }

    function generateIndex3(uint8 _index1, uint8 _index2) private view returns(uint8 _index) {
        uint256 mod = 10;
        uint256 time = block.timestamp;
        uint256 difficulty = block.difficulty;
        uint8 value = uint8(SafeMath.mod(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(time, difficulty, msg.sender))), mod));
        while((value == _index1) || (value == _index2)) {
            time = SafeMath.add(time, 500);
            difficulty = SafeMath.add(difficulty, 700);
            value = uint8(SafeMath.mod(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(time, difficulty, msg.sender))), mod));
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

**FlightSuretyData.sol**

```
import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract FlightSuretyData {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    bool operationalStatus;
    address owner;
    address appContract;

    constructor() public {
        operationalStatus = true;
        owner = msg.sender;
        airlines[owner].registrationStatus = true;
    }

    modifier requireOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Require contract owner");
        _;
    }

    modifier requireApplication() {
        require(msg.sender == appContract, "Require application");
        _;
    }

    modifier requireOperational() {
        require(operationalStatus == true, "Contract is not operational");
        _;
    }

    function registerApplicationContract(address application) external
    requireOwner
    requireOperational {
        appContract = application;
    }

    struct oracle {
        uint8 index1;
        uint8 index2;
        uint8 index3;
        mapping(bytes32 => bool) voteState;
    }

    struct oracleServer {
        mapping(uint256 => oracle) oracles;
        uint256 numberOfOracles;
    }

    mapping(address => oracleServer) private oracleServers;

    function registerOracle(address server, uint8 index1, uint8 index2, uint8 index3) external payable
    requireOperational
    requireApplication {
        uint256 counter = oracleServers[server].numberOfOracles;
        oracleServers[server].oracles[counter].index1 = index1;
        oracleServers[server].oracles[counter].index2 = index2;
        oracleServers[server].oracles[counter].index3 = index3;
        counter = SafeMath.add(counter, 1);
        oracleServers[server].numberOfOracles = counter;
    }
}
```

**How to Run the Project?**

It is easy, just install the dependencies and run the TestingEnv.js file.

**My Environment Specifications**

- Windows 10 Home version 21H1
- Ganache version 2.5.4 ([Use the Ganache Desktop Application from Ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache) and not some dependencies)
- Node version 11.0.0
- Solidity version 0.4.24

**Proof that Works on Remix**

[image]

**Proof that Doesn't Work on Ganache**

[image]

**Request**

How can I solve it? I am stuck on my project because I can make the project work, I've teste others functions of my smart contracts and they are working fine, but when I try to test the oracle generator it gives an error and doesn't work.

What am I missing?